# Angular2 Jasmine - the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I was learning writing test cases using jasmine for my angular2 project.

Following the plunker examples from below link.
https://angular.io/guide/testing

Where i had opened one of the plunker example "*All specs that test the sample application*", The test cases are not running, it is showing issues in browser console window.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY52f.png)

Please let me know If i missed anything...

Answer (score 0):

You need correct the paths references in .spec files. For example:

`import { FakeHeroService } from '../model/testing';`

should be

```
import { FakeHeroService } from '../model/testing/fake-hero.service';
```

and

`import { Hero } from '../model';` should be

```
import { Hero } from '../model/hero';
```

Reason:
When you import file by directory name (e.g. '../model' here), it tries to look for "index.ts" file which should export all necessary files from that directory. Here, we don't have "index.ts" file in "model" directory and "model/testing" directory. So, it fails to locate the functionality and throws error.

Look into console errors and fix all these file reference issues, and you will be good.

See this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/OYByy4K81SDP6zaSIvwZ?p=preview

Comment: Now I understood the issue. Thank You.